# User manual with Doxygen

Tags: documentation, doxygen, user-guide, user-manual

I am trying to write user-manual/tutorial for my library using doxygen (something similar to the user-manual of the doxygen itself! - [link](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/index.html))

I used .md files **subpage**ed from the `mainpage` to create my document hierarchy. I ended up something similar to that of OpenCV ([link](http://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d65/tutorial_table_of_content_introduction.html#gsc.tab=0)), which looks quite nice, but it still does not have many features of that of doxygen user manual. For example, page/section index on the left and page wise table of content on the right.

Is there any way of generating expandable index/table of content and attach it in every pages using doxygen (as in [link](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/index.html))? Is there a better of doing this? Any other tips?

Comment: I think you may want to learn using emacs org mode. It really has everything you can ever wish for and more. Combine it with draw.io for diagrams, export org to html and the wkhtmltopdf it into a pdf and there you have it. https://youtu.be/VjMp_B1V4bI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `GENERATE_TREEVIEW` flag to `YES` in your Doxyfile will cause Doxygen to create the side panel.

Example:

`GENERATE_TREEVIEW = YES`

This feature requires that browsers support JavaScript, DHTML, CSS and frames.

Comment: Oh it is so simple and so precise... Thanks, I am crying of happiness!